# what is the compound or unconditional distribution of a hypergeometric with a binomial number of coloured balls

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a urn with $N$ black balls, and some number of them $K$ are coloured white with probability $p$. So the number of white balls follows a binomial distribution:

$$
{N \choose K}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}
$$

Then suppose you sample $n$ balls from the urn *without* replacement. Among them there are $k$ white balls. **Conditional** on any value of $K$, the distribution would be hypergeometric:

$$
\frac{{ K \choose k } { N- K \choose n - k }}{N \choose n}
$$

But what is the unconditional (aka compound?) distribution if $k$, for all values of $K$?

### edit: partial progress

It seems we should start by multiplying the two, as we normally do when when we have two independent events:

$$
\frac{{ K \choose k } { N- K \choose n - k } {N \choose K}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}}{N \choose n}
$$

I'm very rusty with simplifying factorials, but I *think* this can be simplified to

$$
{ n \choose k }{N-n \choose K-k}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}
$$

But is that correct? does it simplify farther?

### edit 2

It does seem to be correct, since according to the [Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity), if we marginalize over all values of $k$, we end up with the original binomial distribution:

$$
\sum_k { n \choose k }{N-n \choose K-k}p^K(1-p)^{N-K} = {N \choose K}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}
$$

But suppose instead we want to marginalize over $K$?

$$
{ n \choose k }\sum_{K=k}^{N-n}{N-n \choose K-k}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE and good work with the MathJax formatting . Some users prefer you to show your own efforts to do that to avoid unwanted close votes!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the tip, @samerivertwice ! edited

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the answer is another binomial distribution!

Here's why I think so:

$$
{ n \choose k }\sum_{K=k}^{N-n}{N-n \choose K-k}p^K(1-p)^{N-K}
$$

$$
{ n \choose k }\sum_{K=k}^{N-n}{N-n \choose K-k}p^{K-k}p^k(1-p)^{N-n-(K-k)}(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

$$
{ n \choose k }p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\sum_{K=k}^{N-n}{N-n \choose K-k}p^{K-k}(1-p)^{N-n-(K-k)}
$$

And since we sum over all possible values of $K$, the term in the summation equals 1, which leaves us with:

$$
{ n \choose k }p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

Which of course makes perfect sense. If you take any random subset out of a binomial distribution, it should also be a binomial with a smaller sample size.